# Alternate method of getting 'There is no solution' to print

Tags: python, brute-force

> Given integer coefficients of two linear equations with variables x and y, use brute force to find an integer solution for x and y in the range -10 to 10.

Is there an other way to get 'There is no solution.' to print just once? Making a count and adding +1 to that every time there is no solution in both of the lists works once the count has reached over 436. Is there a more efficient solution?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
f = int(input())
x = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
count = 0
for i in x:
    for o in y:
        if a*i + b*o == c and d*i + e*o == f:
            print('x =', i,',', 'y =', o)
        elif a*i + b*o != c and d*i + e*o !=f:
            count += 1
            if count > 436:
                print('There is no solution')
```

Comment: Why is it 436 in the first place? :o

Comment: @kosciej16 I have no clue, I just printed out the count and made it so that it would only print if the count was over that and it worked lol

Comment: I can tell you ;) I guess you have a bug in your `elif` - it should be `or`, not `and`. And your count is very close to 21 * 21 = 441, I guess 5 times just one equation was satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a curiosity, you could use [for else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) syntax too:

```
import itertools

for i, o in itertools.product(range(-10,11), range(-10,11)):
    if a*i + b*o == c and d*i + e*o == f:    
        print('x =', i,',', 'y =', o)
        break
else:
    print('There is no solution')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean variable and break out of the loop when you find a solution:

```
solved = False
for i in x:
    if solved:
        break
    for o in y:
        if a*i + b*o == c and d*i + e*o == f:
            print('x =', i,',', 'y =', o)
            solved = True
            break

if not solved:
    print('There is no solution')
```

And while we are at it, you can use ranges in Python instead of hard coding an array of all integers:

```
solved = False
for i in range(-10,11):
    if solved:
        break
    for o in range(-10,11):
        if a*i + b*o == c and d*i + e*o == f:
            print('x =', i,',', 'y =', o)
            solved = True
            break

if not solved:
    print('There is no solution')
```